# how to tell chrome not use /run/shm or how to make /run/shm not mounted as tmpfs?

Tags: linux, google-chrome, debian, tmpfs

I have the problem with tmpfs and google chrome. When chrome runs, it uses /run/shm to keep some files like `/run/shm/.com.google.Chrome.RnIWmb`, the files are (deleted) but still open, that cause overusage of tmpfs - 500Mb  in good state, that make computer swapping, all slowdown.

some code

```
lsof -n |grep /run/shm |grep '^chrome' |grep deleted|wc -l
314
#-------in lsof:
chrome    27194     user   22u      REG               0,14     524180    2854723 /run/shm/.com.google.Chrome.RnIWmb (deleted)
```

Comment: If Chrome is still running, then it's actually using those files for shared memory (shm), and deleting them will break Chrome.

Comment: @pjc50 that files deleted by chrome, not me.

Comment: Right, but the point is that it's part of Chrome's memory usage. (How much RAM do you have?)

Comment: 4G of memory, the problem that tmpfs worse than cache as i see

Comment: Not mounting `/run/shm` as tmpfs is likely to break your system, and it will not change Chrome's performance. Chrome needs those files, changing what filesystem they are stored on will not change that.

Comment: it does, i just mounted /run/shm with bind and perfomance increased, just want to know proper way. chrome can keep such files on disk, not in ram please, i just not like to spend 500+Mb to speedup shm, because i think it is stupid

Comment: @Gilles i wait a proof link about system broken if i not mount /var/shm as tmpfs

Answer (score 2):

Rather than to remove the tmpfs mount entirely, robbing the other processes on your system this quick and efficient resource, have you tried running chrome using `--disk-cache-dir`?  It seems that google has defaulted to using tmpfs storage either for speed or reduced wear on ssd's, but I don't really know.  A list of command line options for chrome is listed [here](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/).

Comment: idk why, but tmpfs is not efficient and fast on my system, it just make all swapping :) I already umount tmpfs from everywhere and feel much better than early

Comment: also i not understand how come that old good disk caches worse than tmpfs

Comment: also, this is not disk cache, just tried to run `google-chrome --disk-cache-dir /tmp/aaa` and got 
`chrome    17743     user  184u      REG               8,17   1040420     302691 /run/shm/.com.google.Chrome.5rwhEN (deleted)`

Comment: Another option that may work is to actually limit the size of the tmpfs mount so that it doesn't cause your system to start swapping.  The mount option is size=(bytes or percent), which is explained better in `man 8 mount`.  This may limit the number of sites that you can visit in a single instance of chrome, but it will help your memory condition.  Outside of that, the only other reasonable and simple method to handle this is to run chrome in a chroot with the /path/to/chroot/run/shm residing on the disk.  Since I see you have debian tagged, you can use the `schroot` package to do this.

Comment: that cause chrome glitches as it fills out shm drive very fast

Comment: Since i not found other programs that use shm paths i just happy to not let OS mount  it as tmpfs

Comment: I suppose tmpfs is out of the question entirely, which I halfway suspected.  I recommended that first, as it's often better to start with simple solutions before going to more complex ones.  Schroot is a beautiful tool that I use all the time for multiple reasons.  Here is a decent page that will help you get started.  [http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/566]  Since the initscripts won't be running in the chroot, there is no chance for another /run/shm tmpfs mount to be overlaid onto the chroot.  Without hacking into Chrome, I think this might be the easiest solution, even if heavy.

Comment: You can also edit /etc/rcS.d/S01mountkernfs.sh and comment out the line matching `mount_run "$MNTMODE"`.

Comment: I already did all of that (>10years expirence of administration), the question is really about make chrome to stop doing this, also i really wonder why all like tmpfs, as it have less flexibility than OS disk caches

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7130/discussion-between-umeboshi-and-eicto)